# How to get the id of post in which we are commenting using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple posts displayed in my dashboard. They all have same class and same id. But I want to comment a particular post. How can I get the `post_id` and comment input into input the field?

I tried this:

```
<input id="commentbox" name="ipassthepostidhere" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Press enter to post comment">
```

And my JS looks like:

```
$("#commentbox").keyup(function(e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var comment=$('#commentbox').val();
        alert(comment);
    }
});
```

With this JS, I only get the value from the post on the top of the page.

I have this in a `foreach` loop, so as many posts as I get, they will share the same id. Is there any method that I can use for it? Please help me if there is. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are only allowed to have one element with a specific id within an HTML document. You need to figure out how to get unique ids on your elements.

Comment: why can't to give them real (unique) ids? like `post_13` where 13 is the id coming from db.

Comment: You shouldn't have same Id. You can have same class and have id in some data attribute like data-id=id. And then based on the button clicked beside which comment you can get the parent or siblings id

Comment: @Jeff if i do that how do i know on which post's i am typing comment, and assign that id for jquery? I mean okay i can assign id but here $('#id').val how can i put the id of a particular post

Comment: If you're going to be using jquery/javascript often, you should familiarize yourself with [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @PatrickQ can you please provide the example in my case. If its not a big deal for you, please.

Comment: I'd rather that you make an attempt using the two tips I've given you, and then see you update with your progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have twice the same id.
Either make it unique *or* remove it.
Then you can select by a random className (which would be the same for all commentBoxes) and get the current element with `this` or in the EventObject `e`:

```
<input name="ipassthepostidhere" type="text" data-id="12" class="commentBox form-control input-sm">
<input name="ipassthepostidhere2" type="text" data-id="13" class="commentBox form-control input-sm">
<script>
$(".commentBox").keyup(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var comment = e.currentTarget.value;   // e.currentTarget or this is a normal DOM-Element
        var postId = $(this).data('id'); // $(this) is the jQuery-Element
        // or
        // var comment = this.value;
        alert(postId + ' ' + comment);
   }
});
</script>
```

*EDIT*:
Since you wanna get the id of the current post the new comment is related to:
save that in a atrrbute `data-id` or `data-postId` and get it the way I did in the above example.

Comment: Wow this worked like a charm, but how do I get the value of  name="ipassthepostidhere"
in above scenario?'

Comment: i did  this
$(".commentBox").keyup(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var comment = e.currentTarget.value;
        var name = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("name");
        alert(name);
        // or
        // var comment = this.value;
        alert(comment);
   }
}); and that works superb. Thank you Jeff. :)

Comment: great that this worked! Still you should _not mis-use_ the name attribute. rather save such data in custum data-attributes.